# Are "Internal" windows possible in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, window

I am designing a program that allows a user to load and edit multiple files at once. As a result I'm looking at making each of these opened files be displayed as a window within the main window so as to not clutter up the start bar and allow viewing of arbitrary numbers of opened files at once. Here are examples of what I mean.

http://s1151.photobucket.com/user/MosesofEgypt/media/DXT5CompressionExample_zps56bf9024.png.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

I am needing to know if these "internal windows" are possible in python(more specifically with Tkinter). To clarify, what I am looking for is a window that moves with the root window, can be moved and resized, is constrained to the bounds of the root window so it cannot be moved outside it nor is rendered outside it, and does not appear on the start bar.

If it comes down to it, I am sure I can hack together a system that treats a canvas with a click-drag bar as a window, but I would rather do it the right way, if there is a right way.

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't really looked at it but I believe the term you want is "Sub-Forms" It looks like Zope handles it, but I'm sure any GUI tool should handle that. You can look at https://pythonhosted.org/z3c.form/subform.html. That should get you started.

Comment: @user3752226: the OP clearly stated he was using Tkinter so Zope is totally irrelevant here.